# MySQL QUERY for photo ranking

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `psPhotosRating` (
  `id_photo_rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_uploaded_files` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;



CREATE TABLE `psUploadedFiles2` (
  `id_uploaded_files` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `enable` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `file_path` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `category` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tags` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `promo_in_front` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `psPhotosRating`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_photo_rating`);


ALTER TABLE `psPhotosRating`
  MODIFY `id_photo_rating` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `psUploadedFiles2`
  MODIFY `id_uploaded_files` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

psUploadedFiles2 - this is the "photo database"
psPhotosRating - table with votes cast for each photo from psUploadedFiles2

Not every picture has votes.

I need a SQL query displaying a list of images (psUploadedFiles2) sorted by the psPhotosRating rank (number of votes cast).

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: DO you want the images of specific user ?

Comment: I know. I also know that most of what's presented above is irrelevant to the problem at hand. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just join here second table and count results:

```
SELECT count(rat.id_uploaded_files ) as rating, ps.* 
FROM psUploadedFiles2 ps
JOIN psPhotosRating rat ON ps.id_uploaded_files = rat.id_uploaded_files
ORDER BY rating DESC;
```

Comment: thank you. And how to add a column with average votes as a result? In column "rating" I have values from 1 to 5. I want sort by average votes as a result (total number of votes / number of votes)

Comment: @traffse . . . Your question is about counts, not averages -- and this appears to answer the question.  If you have another question ask it as a new question, not in a comment.